# why is there an error code that the attribute doesn't exist in this class when it clearly does

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.13
These are my files below:

C:\PROJECTS\movies_pythonproject\Media.py

```
import webbrowser

class Movie():
    def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

        def show_trailer(self):
            webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
```

C:\PROJECTS\movies_pythonproject\entertainmentcenter.py

```
import media
Above_The_Law = media.Movie("Above The Law",
                        "A former Special Operations Vietnam vet works as a 
Chicago cop and uncovers CIA wrongdoing.",
                        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTgyYTIyOTMtMmQzMC00MDVlLTg0YjItMDVmYjczMzY2ODM1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjQ2MjQ5NzM@._V1_UY268_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg",
                        "https://youtu.be/GZjl-UT4-o4" )

Above_The_Law.show_trailer()
```

When I run entertainmentcenter.py the console gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/PROJECTS/movies_pythonproject/entertainment_center.py", line 8, in 
<module>
  Above_The_Law.show_trailer()
AttributeError: Movie instance has no attribute 'show_trailer'
>>>
```

Comment: Indentation!
  The function is nested within `__init__`

Comment: You're indentation is wrong

Comment: that was actually just my mistake writing this question, sorry. look at my code now (I edited it and fixed it, it still shows the error)

Comment: I don't think you understood what people mean by "indentation". The `show_trailer` method is still indented inside `__init__`.

Comment: oh my god thanks so much guys!! i don't know how i didnt realize that. I appreciate the help you guys are lifesavers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is an indentation problem.

You're defining the `show_trailer` method as a local method inside the `__init__` method.

What you want is:

```
class Movie():
    def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
```

Comment: that was actually just my mistake writing this question, sorry. look at my code now (I edited it and fixed it, it still shows the error)

Comment: Your edit simply fixed a line return in the middle of `poster_image, 
 trailer_youtube` -- that's not the indentation that's causing the problem.

Comment: To be clear -- you've got 8 spaces before `def show_trailer(self):` -- you must reduce that to 4 spaces. (And drop 4 spaces from the subsequent body of the method too, of course.)

Comment: thank you i dont know how i missed that! you are the best! lifesaver

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer as the solution? (Or deleting the question if preferred, since it was a typo, which isn't generally useful for the larger audience.) That'll let others know that the question has been solved, so they can focus on other questions. Thanks!